# Solaris logical domain disappears after hard restart (power loss)

Tags: solaris

We've set up a logical domain (LDOM) on Solaris 11, it persists after a reboot. However, when doing a cold boot (power on), the logical domain isn't found.

Note: We've executed

```
ldm add-spconfig <my_config_name>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the domain's `auto-boot?` setting?  See https://blogs.oracle.com/cmt/entry/what_s_up_with_ldoms1

Comment: Any issues with the SP itself? Have you checked the SP logs for issues, battery problems etc? You're not doing anything wrong afaik.

Comment: Auto-boot is true and the boot device is set to the 'virtual machines' only vdisk

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the lastest server firmware. Update it.
This is the main problem.